# Menu in a custom toolbar not showing in a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment

So I have had asked this multiple times but I can't get a decent answer to my question.

Can someone please tell me why my menu is not showing in my custom toolbar?

PurchaseItemList.java

```
package com.example.devcash.Fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.devcash.R;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class PurchaseItemListFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {

    Toolbar itemListToolbar;
    Spinner itemListSpinner;


    public PurchaseItemListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //inflate the  menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_purchase_item_list, container, false);


        itemListToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_purchaseitemlist);
        itemListSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_allcategories);

        ///
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.custom_spinner_item,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dropdownitempurchase));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        itemListSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        itemListSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        itemListSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    //handles the search menu
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search..");

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is a snippet of my custom toolbar in my fragment_purchase_item_list.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_purchaseitemlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    style="@style/PrimaryHeaderBar"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_allcategories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have tried checking all the related posts from the internet and can't find a decent tutorial on YT. Can someone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue.

Comment: I have tried it but still, menu won't inflate. I will just create a custom menu layout from the toolbar that I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in `onCreateView()` method

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

Also add below line in `onViewCreated()` method

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar(customToolbar as Toolbar?)
```

Where customToolBar is the id of the toolbar added in xml file

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your `onCreateView` method

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```